# Prestashop 1.5.4.x: how to get proper category_link, image, price?

Tags: php, xml, prestashop

Prestashop 1.5.4.x How to get proper category_link, image, price in the code below?
It properly print name, link, manufacturer, category_full. Script show incorrect format for price: `191.26073 instead of 191.26 and 65 instead of 65.00`. For images script show incorrect path: http://mysite.x10.mx/img/p/8-27-large.jpg, the correct patch need be http://mysite.x10.mx/27-thickbox_default/picture.jpg

the full code I used:

```
<?php
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/init.php');
// Get data
$number = (intval(Tools::getValue('n')) ? intval(Tools::getValue('n')) : 10000);
$orderByValues = array(0 => 'name', 1 => 'price', 2 => 'date_add', 3 => 'date_upd', 4 => 'position');
$orderWayValues = array(0 => 'ASC', 1 => 'DESC');
$orderBy = Tools::strtolower(Tools::getValue('orderby', $orderByValues[intval(Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCTS_ORDER_BY'))]));
$orderWay = Tools::strtoupper(Tools::getValue('orderway', $orderWayValues[intval(Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCTS_ORDER_WAY'))]));
if (!in_array($orderBy, $orderByValues))
$orderBy = $orderByValues[0];
if (!in_array($orderWay, $orderWayValues))
$orderWay = $orderWayValues[0];
//$id_category = (intval(Tools::getValue('id_category')) ? intval(Tools::getValue('id_category')) : 1);
$currency = new Currency(intval($cookie->id_currency));
$affiliate = (Tools::getValue('ac') ? '?ac='.Tools::getValue('ac') : '');

$categTree = Category::getRootCategory()->recurseLiteCategTree(0);

function constructTreeNode($node){
    $ret = ';';
    $ret .= $node['id'].'|'.$node['name'].';';
    if(!empty($node['children']))
    {
        $ret .= ';';
        foreach ($node['children'] AS $child)
            $ret .= constructTreeNode($child);
        $ret .= ';';
    }
    return $ret;
}
foreach ($categTree['children'] AS $child)
    $ulTree .= constructTreeNode($child);

$tab_cat=explode(';',$ulTree);
foreach ($tab_cat as $id2cat){
$tab_id2cat=explode('|',$id2cat);
if (!empty($tab_id2cat)) $tab_cat_final[$tab_id2cat[0]]=$tab_id2cat[1];
}

header("Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n";
?>
<root>
<?php
foreach ($tab_cat_final as $id_category=>$name_category){
$products = Product::getProducts(intval($cookie->id_lang), 0, ($number > 10000 ? 10000 : $number), $orderBy, $orderWay, $id_category, true);
foreach ($products AS $product)
{
  $image = Image::getImages(intval($cookie->id_lang), $product['id_product']);
  $prix=Product::getPriceStatic($product['id_product']);
  if ($product['reduction_percent']>0) $prix_promo=$prix*(1-$product['reduction_percent']/100);else $prix_promo=($prix-$product['reduction_price']);


  echo "<item>\n";
  echo "<name><![CDATA[".$product['name']."]]></name>\n";
                echo "<link><![CDATA[".htmlspecialchars($link->getproductLink($product['id_product'], $product['link_rewrite'], Tools::getValue('id_category'))).$affiliate."]]></link>\n";
  echo "<price>".$prix."</price>\n";
  echo "<image>"._PS_BASE_URL_.__PS_BASE_URI__."img/p/".$image[0]['id_product']."-".$image[0]['id_image']."-large.jpg</image>\n";
  echo "<category_full><![CDATA[".$name_category."]]></category_full>\n";
                echo "<category_link><![CDATA[".htmlspecialchars($link->getcategoryLink($category['id_category'], $category['link_rewrite'], Tools::getValue('id_category'))).$affiliate."]]></category_link>\n";
  echo "<manufacturer><![CDATA[".$product['manufacturer_name']."]]></manufacturer>\n";
  echo "<reference><![CDATA[".$product['id_product']."]]></reference>\n";
  echo "</item>\n";
}
}
?>
</root>
```

Comment: I suggest you contact Prestashop for your support options. Apart from that it is free software and you can just change it to your needs. So what did you try so far and where did you hit the roadblock with that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code as it should be:

```
$default_currency = new Currency(Configuration::get('PS_CURRENCY_DEFAULT'));
foreach ($tab_cat_final as $id_category=>$name_category)
{
$products = Product::getProducts(intval($cookie->id_lang), 0, ($number > 10000 ? 10000 : $number), $orderBy, $orderWay, $id_category, true);
foreach ($products AS $product)
{
$price = Product::getPriceStatic($product['id_product']);
if ($product['reduction_percent'] > 0)
$prix_promo = $price * (1 - $product['reduction_percent'] / 100);
else
$prix_promo = ($price-$product['reduction_price']);

$id_image = Image::getCover($product['id_product']);
$image_link = $link->getImageLink($product['link_rewrite'], $id_image, 'large_default');

echo "<item>\n";
echo "<name><![CDATA[".$product['name']."]]></name>\n";
echo "<link><![CDATA[".htmlspecialchars($link->getproductLink($product['id_product'],     $product['link_rewrite'], Tools::getValue('id_category'))).$affiliate."]]></link>\n";
echo "<price>".Tools::displayPrice($price, $default_currency)."</price>\n";
echo "<image>".$image_link."</image>\n";
echo "<category_full><![CDATA[".$name_category."]]></category_full>\n";
echo "<category_link><![CDATA[".htmlspecialchars($link-    >getcategoryLink($category['id_category'], $category['link_rewrite'],     Tools::getValue('id_category'))).$affiliate."]]></category_link>\n";
echo "<manufacturer><![CDATA[".$product['manufacturer_name']."]]></manufacturer>\n";
echo "<reference><![CDATA[".$product['id_product']."]]></reference>\n";
echo "</item>\n";
}
}
```

Here's to get the price right:

```
$default_currency = new Currency(Configuration::get('PS_CURRENCY_DEFAULT'));
Tools::displayPrice($prix, $default_currency)
```

Here's to get the image right:

```
$id_image = Image::getCover($product['id_product']);
$image_link = $link->getImageLink($product['link_rewrite'], $id_image, 'large_default');
```

Comment: I tried modified version, but not work properly, below is full code:

Comment: It show wrong image path: `http://mysite.com/img/p/Array-large_default.jpg` For price, I want show price without currency symbol, just digits.  It still not show category_link, i.e. show `http://mysite.com/en/`-  instead of `http://www.mysite.com/7-cellphones/` Finally, how to get it show `<model>6120</model>` and `<in_stock>7</in_stock>?` quantity?